# How to write a function that takes a string and prints the letters in decreasing order of frequency?

Tags: python

I got this far:

```
def most_frequent(string):
    d = dict()
    for key in string:
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = 1
        else:
            d[key] += 1
    return d

print most_frequent('aabbbc')
```

Returning:

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3}
```

Now I need to:

1. reverse the pair
2. sort by number by decreasing order
3. only print the letters out

Should I convert this dictionary to tuples or list?

Comment: What do you want to output for 'aabbbc'?  My guess was 'bbbaac' or 'bac'

Comment: ok, I updated my answer below

Answer (score 13):

Here's a one line answer

```
sortedLetters = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k))
```

Comment: Wow... very nice. I didn't even think to look for a built-in that does the job directly!

Comment: Note that reversing is still necessary here. Frequencies also need to be trimmed. If you import operator, you can do all of this in one line: map(operator.itemgetter(0), sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)).

Comment: @Stephan: How about adding your own post so I can vote for it?

Answer (score 5):

This should do it nicely.

```
def frequency_analysis(string):
    d = dict()
    for key in string:
        d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + 1
    return d

def letters_in_order_of_frequency(string):
    frequencies = frequency_analysis(string)
    # frequencies is of bounded size because number of letters is bounded by the dictionary, not the input size 
    frequency_list = [(freq, letter) for (letter, freq) in frequencies.iteritems()]
    frequency_list.sort(reverse=True)
    return [letter for freq, letter in frequency_list]

string = 'aabbbc'
print letters_in_order_of_frequency(string)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that returns a list of tuples rather than a dictionary:

```
import operator

if __name__ == '__main__':

    test_string = 'cnaa'

    string_dict = dict()
    for letter in test_string:
        if letter not in string_dict:
            string_dict[letter] = test_string.count(letter)

    # Sort dictionary by values, credits go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-dictionary-in-python-by-the-value/613218#613218
    ordered_answer = sorted(string_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    print ordered_answer
```

Comment: Dammit! I was just typing a response using operator! :-) +1 for being faster with the best answer

Comment: Note that it's possible to give reverse=True as an argument to sorted(). Arguably that would be a little more efficient.
I'd say that the use of count() here is less efficient than the alternative used by other answers, because this requires multiple iterations over the string.

Comment: +1 This answer is closest to how the standard library implements *collections.Counter.most_common()*.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.7 supports this use case directly:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('abracadabra').most_common()
[('a', 5), ('r', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

Comment: lovely counter, can't live without it. just for curious, when data is scaling up,  the memory can't hold the whole data. how to scale up our collections.Counter according? I want process some log files when can be done with Counter easily except it's size is far beyond computer's memory size now.

Answer (score 2):

chills42 lambda function wins, I think but as an alternative, how about generating the dictionary with the counts as the keys instead?

```
def count_chars(string):
    distinct = set(string)
    dictionary = {}
    for s in distinct:
        num = len(string.split(s)) - 1
        dictionary[num] = s
    return dictionary

def print_dict_in_reverse_order(d):
    _list = d.keys()
    _list.sort()
    _list.reverse()
    for s in _list:
        print d[s]
```

Comment: what if 2 chars has same count, your code will give incorrect result

Comment: Why? The order the two letters with the same count are printed in is not defined, either in the question or my solution.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** This will do what you want. I'm stealing **chills42** line and adding another:

```
sortedLetters = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k))
sortedString = ''.join([c[0] for c in reversed(sortedLetters)])
```

------------*original answer*------------

To print out the sorted string add another line to **chills42** one-liner:

```
''.join(map(lambda c: str(c[0]*c[1]), reversed(sortedLetters)))
```

This prints out 'bbbaac'

If you want single letters, 'bac' use this:

```
''.join([c[0] for c in reversed(sortedLetters)])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def most_frequent(s):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for c in s:
        d[c] += 1

    return "".join([
        k for k, v in sorted(
        d.iteritems(), reverse=True, key=lambda (k, v): v)
    ])
```

**EDIT:**

here is my one liner:

```
def most_frequent(s):
    return "".join([
        c for frequency, c in sorted(
            [(s.count(c), c) for c in set(s)], reverse=True
        )
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out s.count()! upvoted just for that piece of information!

Comment: To be fair, hyperboreean mentioned the count method first. Personally, I don't like that approach because it iterates through the string for every letter. Although, it helps for making an elegant one liner :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code for your `most_frequent` function:

```
>>> a = 'aabbbc'
>>> {i: a.count(i) for i in set(a)}
{'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 3}
```

this particular syntax is for py3k, but it's easy to write something similar using syntax of previous versions. it seems to me a bit more readable than yours.

Comment: This works but is slow compared to Chill's version or the *collections.Counter* version.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reversedSortedFrequency(string)
   from collections import defaultdict
   d = defaultdict(int)
   for c in string:
     d[c]+=1
   return sorted([(v,k) for k,v in d.items()], key=lambda (k,v): -k)
```

Comment: Why not use *reversed=True* instead of a key function to invert k?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **fixed version** (thank you for pointing out bugs)

```
def frequency(s):
    return ''.join(
        [k for k, v in
        sorted(
            reduce(
                lambda d, c: d.update([[c, d.get(c, 0) + 1]]) or d, 
                list(s), 
                dict()).items(),
            lambda a, b: cmp(a[1], b[1]),
            reverse=True)])
```

I think the use of `reduce` makes the difference in this sollution compared to the others...

In action:

```
>>> from frequency import frequency
>>> frequency('abbbccddddxxxyyyyyz')
'ydbxcaz'
```

This **includes extracting the keys (and counting them)** as well!!! Another nice property is the initialization of the dictionary on the same line :)

Also: **no includes**, just builtins.

The `reduce` function is kinda hard to wrap my head around, and setting dictionary values in a `lambda` is also a bit cumbersome in python, but, ah well, it works!

Comment: How can this be voted up? You sort by alphabet, not frequency. I do not have enough reputation to vote this down...

Comment: oops! sorting on the string was only done to tokenize it. Should have used list instead, so as not to confuse you and myself, since the output is random order, namely keys().

Comment: Fixed the function, adding sorting to the dictionary containing frequencies. This might also be a prime example of why one-liners are both fun to write and bad to have in production code!