# Writing a function to print letters of a string according to their frequency compalsarily using dictionary and tuple

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I tried to define a function to **print the letters of a word in decreasing order of their frequency**, *using dictionary and tuple*. Two similar questions were [Counting repeated characters in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python) and [How to write a function that takes a string and prints the letters in decreasing order of frequency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665942/how-to-write-a-function-that-takes-a-string-and-prints-the-letters-in-decreasing?rq=1), but the difference is the sorting (by frequency) part and the algorithm.

Here's what I wrote :-

```
def most_frequent(string):
    d = dict()        #Created a dictionary
    for c in string:
        d[c] = d.get(c,0)+1  #Employed the get method to get the value of the key c
    t = d.items()     #Created a list of tuples of key-value pairs
    for letter, frequency in t:
        letter, frequency = frequency, letter  #Swapped the elements of the tuples
    t.sort(reverse = True)     #Sorting in descending order
    for frequency, letter in t:
        print (frequency," ",letter)
```

The error message produced when I call the function with "bookshopkeeper" as the argument is :-

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
        most_frequent("bookshopkeeper")
      File "<pyshell#1>", line 8, in most_frequent
        t.sort(reverse = True)
    AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I used the get method to eliminate use of if conditionals. I am using python 3.3. Please **fix the code**. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please fix the code identation.

Comment: Please do fix your indentation, your code is hard to comprehend in terms of logic. Also, what exactly isn't working about it?

Comment: Isn't working means what? Crashes with error? Incorrect output? Nasal demon infestation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting repeated characters in a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: [Please read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions) for what constitutes an on-topic "fix my code" question.  As posted, this is clearly off topic and I have voted to close it.

Comment: To fix indentation: copy your code (with correct indentation) into the question box. Select all of the code, and hit `Ctrl-K` (`Cmd-K` on OS X).

Answer (score 3):

You're better off using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
dct = collections.Counter(string)
print(dct.most_common())
print(list(reversed(dct.most_common())))  # least common :-)
```